# AP Chapter 2 Worksheet 1 Methods

Tags: java

I ran the code and it was successful. The objective was to Number the marked statements from 1 to 6, in the blanks at the right for the following program fragment, to show the logical order in which they are executed. I'm confused on how to number the marked statements. The code and the outputs are below.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Problem1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Number");
        int number1 = 1;
        float number2 = 2.5f;
        Problem1 object1 = new Problem1();
        object1.doThis(number1, number2);
        object1.alsoDo(number1, number2);
        System.out.println(number1 + " " + number2);
    }

    public void alsoDo(int value1,float value2){
        System.out.println(value1 + value2);
    }

    public void doThis(int num1, float num2) {
        int num3 = 3;
        System.out.println(num1 + num2 + num3);
    }
}
```

Number
6.5
3.5
1 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which statements are supposed to be marked, but here's the breakdown on how to do it.

One of the essential skills of becoming a programmer is breaking problems down into smaller problems. You're given a program, and you need to break down each line of code to see how it fits into the bigger picture.

You also need to know that code doesn't always execute in a "linear" fashion. When you call a method, such as `doThis()` or `alsoDo()`, the code inside the method is executed. Even though `System.out.println(value1 + value2);` is typed after `System.out.println(number1+" " + number2);`, the former is executed first.

In your example, our main method is:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    System.out.println("Number");
    int number1= 1;
    float number2= 2.5f;
    Problem1 object1 = new Problem1();
    object1.doThis(number1,number2);
    object1.alsoDo(number1,number2);
    System.out.println(number1+" " + number2);
}
```

The program always starts by running the `main` method. When the `main` method is executed, the program prints 'Number'. Then, it initializes an integer type variable to 1 and then a floating type variable to 2.5. It creates an object of type `Problem1`, which is the main class.

The execution of those statements are fairly straightforward, as the program proceeds line by line. The next line is where it gets interesting.

The `doThis()` method is called on `number1` and `number2`. Instead of proceeding down to the next line, the program "jumps" to the `doThis()` method. It executes the following:

```
public void doThis(int num1, float num2){
    int num3= 3;
    System.out.println(num1+num2+num3);
}
```

This method takes 2 parameters, one `int` and one `float`. It then prints the sum of those two parameters and 3.

After this method is successfully executed, we can go to the next line of the main method. 
`object1.alsoDo(number1, number2);`

Like before, we execute a new method that is defined later on in the class. We "jump" to `alsoDo()`.

```
public void alsoDo(int value1,float value2){
    System.out.println(value1 + value2);
}
```

This method has the same parameters as `doThis()`, but a slightly different function. It prints the sum of the two parameters.

Now, we can go to the last line of the main method. 
`System.out.println(number1+" " + number2);`

This just prints the two numbers separated by a space.

Like I said in the beginning, the code does not execute in a linear fashion. Even though the print method in the main method is on an earlier line number than the other two, it is the last to execute.

Comment: Nice, it is interesting how Java reads lines of code. This information is valuable, thank you very much.

Comment: For the worksheet, I numbered the marked statements in this sequence: 1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 2.

Answer (score 0):

Which of those statements are marked? It seems (because it's an AP question) that the question wants you to just write on the page and number the lines in the order that they'll be executed in.

Typically the code would just be executed from the top down so you would just be able to mark them:

```
1
2
3
```

and so on, but if you call a function within your main method you'll get something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    some line of code; //Executes first
    some line of code; //Executes second
    function();
    some line of code; //Executes fourth
}
private void function(){
    some line of code; //Executes third
}
```

The question wants you to identify the order in which the lines of code above are run.

Answer (score -1):

The lines starting wtih public void are the methods of the Problem1 class.  The only one called automatically is main().  When you run "java Problem1" the JVM starts up the main() method and it runs from the top down, until the main() method ends.

A good text editor like [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) or just about any IDE will let you see which bracket sets match up with each other.

Comment: What is Geany?  Thank you for the explanation it helps a lot since I'm new to Java.

Comment: Geany is just a really good text editor/lightweight IDE that is cross platform.  Notepad++ or any other programmer-oriented text editor should give the same or similar functionality.

Comment: Nice, I will do more research on Geany and see how it works. The Java Complier I use is Browxy.